# .net core model validation

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently I am using ActionFilterAttribute to validate the model. I am facing the issue if I give an integer value in the string field it will automatically converted to a string instead of throwing error.
Ex:

```
{
   "Id":1,
   "employeeName":1
}
```

in the above model class employeeName data type is a string.

model validator:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var message = string.Join("; ", context.ModelState.Values
                                        .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
                
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(message);
            }
        }
```

I want to throw an error like value must be a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can **enable client-side model validation**.

- **Client-side validation** prevents submission until the form is valid.
- In other words, if the data you enter is not a string type, an error message will be given on the client side.
- **[Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-side-validation)**